# Declaration of Long (Modifier) in c

Tags: c

#### Original question

I have a piece of code here:

```
unsigned long int a =100000;
int a =100000UL;
```

Do the above two lines represent the same thing?

---

#### Revised question

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long int x=50000*1024000;
    printf("%ld\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

For a `long int`, my compiler uses 8 bytes, so the max range is (2^63-1). So here `50000*1024000` results in something which is definitely less than the max range of `long int` So why does my compiler warn of overflow and give the wrong output?

Comment: C does not have _modifiers_. What do you mean? And why do you expect two different types represeent the same thing? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Rolled back. You must not edit a question, leaving an answer without context! This is no discussion/live editing site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Original question

The two definitions are not the same.

The types of the variables are different — `unsigned long` versus (signed) `int`.  The behaviour of these types is quite different because of the difference in signedness.  They also may have quite different ranges of valid values.

Technically, the numeric constants are different too; the first is a (signed) `int` unless `int` cannot hold the value 100,000, in which case it will be (signed) `long` instead.  That will be converted to `unsigned long` and assigned to the first `a`.  The other constant is an `unsigned long` value because of the `UL` integer suffix, and will be converted to `int` using the normal rules.  If `int` cannot hold the value 100,000, the normal conversion rules will apply.  It is legitimate, though very unusual these days, for `sizeof(int) == 2 * sizeof(CHAR_BIT)` where `CHAR_BIT` is 8 — so `int` is a 16-bit signed type.  This is normally treated as a `short` and normally `int` is a 32-bit signed type, but the standard does not rule out the alternative.

Most likely, the two variants of `a` both end up holding the value 100,000, but they are not the same because of the difference in signedness.

#### Revised question

The arithmetic is done in terms of the two operands of the `*` operator, and those are `50000` and `1024000`.  Each of those fits in a 32-bit `int`, so the calculation is done as `int` — and the result would be `51200000000`,  but that requires at least 36 bits to represent the value, so you have 32-bit arithmetic overflow, and the result is undefined behaviour.

After the arithmetic is complete, the `int` result is converted to 64-bit `long` — not before.

The compiler is correct to warn, and because you invoked undefined behaviour, anything that is printed is 'correct'.

To fix the code, you can write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long x = 50000L * 1024000L;
    printf("%ld\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Strictly, you only need one of the two `L` suffixes, but symmetry suggests using both.  You could use one or two `(long)` casts instead if you prefer.  You can save on spaces too, if you wish, but they help the readability of the code.

Comment: You answered this after OP edited it to a different question and before another user rolled it back. I suggest updating this answer or closing the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — thanks for noticing and giving me a heads up.  I've edited the question so that both the original and the revised versions are visible, and I've expanded my answer to address both variants of the question.  The other contemporaneous answer really isn't careful enough in the way it expresses the differences, but was written before the question was edited (back in 2017) and hence should not be penalized for not addressing the revised question.  On the whole, though, it needs quite a lot of work to rescue it (and the comment chain should be cleaned up if it is improved).

Answer (score -1):

The long int and int are not necessarily the same, but they might be. Unsigned and signed are not the same thing. Numerical constants can represent the same value without being the same thing, as in 100000 and 100000UL (the former being a signed int, the latter being unsigned long)

Comment: `unsigned long int` and `int` are **never** the same thing. Even `long` and `int` are not, even if both have the same width!

Comment: Then What does UL represent in

Comment: @Olaf: a 4-byte int and a 4-byte long int are the same thing *in that sense*. But yeah, I noted that they aren't necessarily the same. There's really nothing there to argue about. There's no suggestion to treat them as the same thing.

Comment: UL at the end of a literal represents unsigned long, as I said.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson: They are definitively **not** They are different types which may have different implications, e.g. for argument passing! You mix language and the implementation, which is a bad idea.

Comment: You phrase your replies as arguments, which I fail to see the necessity of. Thanks for the additional clarifications, though. Yes, they are different types which may have different implications.